# Get data from Firebase to List is null (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firebase to a List, I don't want use StreamBuilder, I just want to get data to List to use something later. I try to do this but it show The method 'add' was called on null.

```
 List<Map <dynamic, dynamic>> maps;
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) =>  maps.add(doc.data) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the `maps` variable, so `maps.add(doc.data)` is indeed called on an uninitialized variable (`null`).

To fix this problem, initialize `maps` when you declare it:

```
var maps = List<Map <dynamic, dynamic>>();
```

---

On the problem you mention in the comments: my guess is that you're printing the map length outside of `.listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) =>  maps.add(doc.data) ))`, which won't work because data loading happens asynchronously.

The simplest fix for that **new** problem is to use `get` and `await`:

```
var data = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .snapshots()
    .get()
data.documents.forEach((doc) =>  maps.add(doc.data) ));
print(maps.length)
```

Alternatively, you can keep using `listen`, but then move the print operation into the callback:

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => {

    data.documents.forEach((doc) =>  maps.add(doc.data));
    print(maps.length);
});
```

Or slightly simpler:

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => {

    var maps = data.documents.map((doc) => doc.data);
    print(maps.length);
});
```

Comment: "it's still not working" is not very actionable. What happens when you make this change? What error do you get? When you step through the code, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do? The more explicit your are about what happens, the better the chances we can help you.

Comment: I create a button when I press  it get data from cloud-firebase to maps, but I print(maps.length) it show value 0

Comment: Your code doesn't show the printing of `maps.length`, but my guess is that you do that **outside** of the `listen` callback, which won't work. Also note that if the error changed from "The method 'add' was called on null", your original problem is solved, and you're dealing with a new problem.